# Process tables by number of rows, row height, and alert if no tables exist in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code right now:

```
var table = $(source).children('table').map(function() {
if (this.rows.length >= 4) {
    return $(this).outerHTML();
} else {
    return null;
}
}).get();
```

This will get tables by number of rows, but how would I get the tables by row height (if height < 100 px) also and also alert if no tables are in the array (if the array is empty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/), like this:

```
var table = $(source).children('table').map(function() {
if ($(this).find("tr").is(function(){ $(this).height() < 100 }) {
    return $(this).outerHTML();
} else {
    return null;
}
}).get();
//Now check size:
if(table.length == 0) alert("There are no tables");
```

What are we doing with `.is()`? We are searching if **at least one** of the children `tr` has height lower than 100, and ignore the table if this condition is not fulfilled.

Hope this helps. Cheers

**EDIT** For your new demands:

```
  var table = $(source).children('table').map(function() {
    if (!$(this).find("tr").is(function(){ $(this).height() >= 100 } &&
         $(this).find("tr").size() > 4  ) {
        return $(this).outerHTML();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
  }).get();
  //Now check size:
  if(table.length == 0) alert("There are no tables");
```

Comment: I would also want to include if there are greater than 4 rows or not

Comment: and I also want ALL the rows to be less than 100

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by the first question, but for the alert:

```
if($(source).children('table').length===0){
   alert("no tables!");
}
```